# Xocde - ERROR ITMS-90683 Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File

Tags: ios, xcode

> ERROR ITMS-90683: "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)."

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add “NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription” key to info.plist file to and inform your app needs to the health updates as the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem.